# How can I query Solr to get a list with all field-names prefixed by a string?

Tags: solr, solr6

I would like to create an output based on the field-names of my Solr index objects.

What I have are objects like this e.g.:

```
{
    "Id":"ID12345678",
    "GroupKey":"Beta",
    "PricePackage":5796.0,
    "PriceCoupon":5316.0,
    "PriceMin":5316.0
}
```

Whereby the `Price*` fields may vary from object to object, some might have more than three of those, some less, however they would be always prefixed with `Price`.

***How can I query Solr to get a list with all field-names prefixed by `Price`?***

I've looked into filters, facets but could not find any clue on how to do this, as all examples - e.g. regex facet - are in regard to the field-value, not the field-name itself. Or at least I could not adapt it to that.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve a list of all field names defined with a name that starts with `Price`, or do you only want the fields that start with `Price` to be included in the response?

Comment: I want to retrieve a list of all field names defined with a name that starts with Price

Comment: You can use the `/solr/collection/admin/luke?wt=json&show=schema` endpoint to retrieve all defined fields for your schema, then filter that further in your application as necessary

Comment: ```/solr/myCollection/schema/fields?wt=json``` got me a JSON of all fields, which I could filter as I like with JS, that is already sufficient, thanks!

```/solr/myCollection/schema/fields?fl=PriceMin,Id&wt=json``` works too, however, ```/solr/myCollection/schema/fields?fl=Price*&wt=json``` does not

Comment: Something else to keep in mind with the schema API (/solr/myCollection/schema/fields) is that it won't report dynamically created fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a comma separated list of all existing field names if you query for 0 documents and use the csv response writer (wt parameter) to generate the field name list.

For example if you request `/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=csv` you get a list of all fields. If you only want fields prefixed with Price you could also add the field list parameter (fl) to limit the fields.

So the request to `/solr/collection/select?q=*:*&wt=csv&fl=Price*`should return the following response:

```
PricePackage,PriceCoupon,PriceMin
```

With this solution you get all fields existing including dynamic fields.