# Filter records in solr if fields starting with a pattern exists

Tags: solr

I have a solr index where records may or maynot have certain fields based on the availability of data for the fields. All the field names are starting with `attr_`
How to filter all records if a record has atleast on field starting with the field name as `attr_`

The example field names could be `attr_score`, `attr_size`, `attr_weight` etc.

As a user, i don't know how many such fields exists, it has to be a generic way to filter.

Answer (score 1):

Add an additonal field; `has_attr_field` and populate it with a value if the document has an attribute.

A `BoolField` would work fine.

You can also add a `has_attr_fields` field as a string, and then add `attr_score`, `attr_size`, etc. to that field, which will allow you to query for a specific set of attribute fields directly (i.e. a combination of them, if multiple `attr_` fields can make up the score (if it's only a single field, `attr_size:[* TO *]` will give you all documents that have a value in that field).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i don't have the freedom to add another field. My concern, is with the existing setup is there any possibility. 
But i really appreciate your suggestion, unfortunately I am not in power to do that.

Comment: Then you're going to need to create a list of all possible fields and add those as a large has-a-value-for-this-field-list. I'm not aware of any wildcard field search. Do you have access to the Solr side of things (i.e. can you add an update handler)? Do you only have query access? The CSV handler can give you a list of defined fields: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55474250/how-can-i-query-solr-to-get-a-list-with-all-field-names-prefixed-by-a-string